# Application for visualizing website relationship in graphic

Tags: webapp-rec

What is the best online application (Java or Javascript) or basic application (Win) to visualizing website relationship in graphic?

Application should draw lines between website pages starting from given address.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean visitors flow report (aka. page transitions report):

[Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1709395?hl=en) (closed-source + free) ([more info](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/10/introducing-flow-visualization.html)):

[image]

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/docs/transitions/) (open-source + free):

[image]

You might also be interested in looking for [Sankey diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram), e.g. using D3.js (open-source + free): http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/

[image]